# Simulate a POST request with the object parameters and an extra id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm doing RSpec tests in a ROR application and I need to simulate a post action in order to test a controller.

The normal use is like this:

```
post :candidate, candidate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:candidate)
```

My problem is that I also need to pass an id that comes from the url. The action url is this one:

```
candidates POST    /positions/:id/candidate(.:format)      positions#candidate
```

So what I need is something like this:

```
post :candidate, candidate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:candidate), id: position.id
```

How can I simulate a post request with object attributes and also an id?

In the normal use the output in the rails server is this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "candidate"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "email"=>"john@gmail.com", "phone_number"=>"+351911111111", "skype_id"=>"qwe", "linkedin_url"=>"qwe", "why_work_with_us"=>"qwe", "resume_url"=>"qwe", "portfolio_url"=>"qwe"}, "id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: 'something like' `post :candidate, candidate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:candidate), id: position.id`? Doesn't this already work and do what you want? If not, how does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send all the required params in a params hash. So, build a params hash and then pass that to the `post` call like this:

```
let(:params) { { candidate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:candidate), id: position.id } }
post :candidate, params
```